# robots.txt Disallow: /click What is disallowed?

Tags: web-crawler, robots.txt

I would like to scrape a web site. It has the following in it's robots.txtfile, but I'm not exactly sure what it is they don't want me to do:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /click
```

There is no click subdirectory. Or they don't want me to access anything that would normally require clicking (like submitting data via a form)? They sure aren't making it easy in any case - the main page's form GETS to a site that sets a cookie that is read by a third page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that no bot should crawl *any* URLs whose paths **start with** the string `click`.

For example, the following URLs should be blocked:

- `example.com/click`
- `example.com/click.html`
- `example.com/click/`
- `example.com/click/foo/bar`
- `example.com/clicker`

The following URLs would still be allowed:

- `example.com/foo/click`
- `example.com/fooclick`
- `example.com/clic`

You can find the original robots.txt specification at http://www.robotstxt.org/wc/robots.html.